# image upload into subfolder in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

i'm new to codeigniter..please help me in uploading image in codeigniter.first i need to create a sub folder inside "codeigniter/userimage/" with the user id as folder name. i did that.this is my controller function

```
function update(){
    $uppath="/var/www/html/codeigniter/userimage/";
    $sess_id=  $this->session->userdata('userid');
    $folder=$uppath.$sess_id;
    if(!is_dir($folder))
    mkdir ($folder,777);

    if($x>0){
        $config['upload_path']='./userimage/'.$folder.'/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '9000';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '1000';
        echo 'haii'; 
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        echo 'heloooo'; 
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('picfile')) {
            print_r( $this->upload->display_error() );die;
        }
        else {
            $image=$this->upload->do_upload('picfile');
            // echo 'uploaded';
            echo $image;
        }
    }
}
```

i'm calling my method update written inside the model 'home' from the view 'profileinfo'.

my view profileinfo is:

```
`<?php
  $fn='';
 $ln='';
 $un='';
 $em='';
 $b='';
 $gr='';
 foreach ($query as $row){
 $fn=$row->firstname;
 $ln=$row->lastname;
  $un=$row->username;
  $em=$row->email;
 $b=$row->bday;
 $gr=$row->gender;
}
?>
 <html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1><u>My Profile Details</u></h1>
    <br><br><div id="viewdiv" align="center">

          <div align="right" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 20px;"> 
      <a  href="home">Back</a></div>
       <?php echo form_open_multipart('home/update');?>
<br>
<table border="0" align="center">
    <tr class='spacerow'>
        <td>
            <h2>  Name:</h2>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo"<input type='text' name='first' value='$fn'>";?>
        <?php echo"<input type='text' name='last' value='$ln'>";?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='spacerow'>
        <td>
            <h2>   User Name:</h2>
        </td>
        <td>
             <?php echo"<input type='text' name='uname' value='$un'>";?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='spacerow'>
        <td>
            <h2>   Date of birth:</h2>
        </td>
        <td>
           <?php echo"<input type='text' name='dobb' id='datepicker' value='$b'>";?> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='spacerow'>
        <td>
            <h2>    Gender: </h2>
        </td>
        <?php
        if($gr=="male"){
            ?>
        <td>
            <?php echo"<h3>Male:<input type='radio' name='gen' value='male' checked>";?>
             <?php echo"Female:<input type='radio' name='gen' value='female' ></h3>";?>
        </td>
        <?php
                    }
                  else{  
        ?>
        <td>
             <?php echo"<h3>Male:<input type='radio' name='gen' value='male'>";?>
            <?php echo"Female:<input type='radio' name='gen' value='female' checked></h3>";?>
        </td>
        <?php
                  }
                  ?>
    </tr>

    <tr class='spacerow'>
        <td>
            <h2>    Email:</h2>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo"<input type='text' name='mail' value='$em'>";?>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr class='spacerow'>
        <td>
            <h2> Profile Picture:</h2>
</td>
<td>
   <input type="file" name="picfile"> 
   <p>if you want to change your profile picture,browse here..</p>


</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td><br>
        <center> <input type="submit" name="update" value="update"></center>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>   
    </tr>


</table>



    </div>    
</body>
```

`
the sub folder "$folder" is creating inside userimage and i want to store the uploaded image into that sub folder.my problem is the image is not uploading. you can see i put two echo statement before and after loading upload library. but i'm getting only the output "haii".. i dont get any idea about what is the problem..please anybody help me.. thanks..

Comment: So what exactly is returned by the do_upload function? What is the error message?

Comment: you need to give 777 permission of folder with chmod().

Comment: @Technoh: no error messages are showing.. when I click the button after browse the image the URL shows the page is moving to the specified method in the controller..but image is not uploading... that’s my problem..

Comment: @Prasannjit: I gave that permission through command line already..

Answer (score 0):

First of all use :

```
$uppath='./codeigniter/userimage/';
```

And what is your file field name? if its not `userfile` then provide the field name like this:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('field_name'))
```

And lastly print the errors like this to debug:

```
print_r( $this->upload->display_error() );die;
```

**EDIT:**

```
function update(){
    $uppath="/var/www/html/codeigniter/userimage/";
    $sess_id=  $this->session->userdata('userid');
    $folder=$uppath.$sess_id;
    if(!is_dir($folder))
    mkdir ($folder,777);

    if($x>0){
        $config['upload_path']      = './userimage/'.$sess_id.'/';
        $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size']         = '9000';
        $config['max_width']        = '1024';
        $config['max_height']       = '1000';
        echo 'haii'; 
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        //$this->upload->initialize($config);
        echo 'heloooo'; 
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('picfile')) {
            print_r( $this->upload->display_errors() );die;
        }
        else {
            $image=$this->upload->do_upload('picfile');
            // echo 'uploaded';
            echo $image;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I gave the $uppath like you said..it shows error that "no such directory is found"..and my sub folder is creating when I gave full path.. my problem is the browsed image is not uploading..

Comment: the directory `codeigniter`, is it the `root directory` of your project? If `yes then` write `$uppath='./userimage/';`

Comment: hai sir..thanks for your help.. i posted the edited code above as you said.. but again its not working.. will you please take a look into the edited question once again? plz?

Comment: @user007 what error are you getting in apache error log after executing your code? can you post your error?

Comment: Change this line : `$config['upload_path']='./userimage/'.$sess_id.'/';`

Comment: @MahavirMunot: I didn't get any error sir..when i run this code a new page with printing echo'haii' statement which i put in the code is coming.. :(

Comment: @NiloySaha: i run my code after changing the line as you said..again i got the page same as before..with printing "haii"..

Comment: hey guys.. when i use this line "var_dump($this->input->post('picfile') );" i got the erroe "bool(false)".. Do u know the reason for that?

Comment: Edited the above try once, `input type file` in not in `POST` array thats why it returned false. @user007

Comment: @Niloy: ohh..so should i use foreach($_file as $value) to get the file name?? is this is the reason behind my file is not uploading?? :(

Comment: Does it prints `echo 'heloooo'; `? or not? Change `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');` in `index.php` at the root of your project folder. From where are you calling `update()`? Post your form too. In your form have you included `enctype = multipart/form-data`? check once and reply.

Comment: @NiloySaha: haii sir.. i updated my question with my form..yeah i included mutipart with my form_open and i'm calling update form this view named profileinfo.. when i did image upload alone in another page from form submit i got the answer..but when i did the same within the form my library upload is not loading.. :(

Comment: @NiloySaha: no sir..its not printing echo 'helloo'... its only printing the first echo 'haii'..